# What are the differences between these two directories for startup items?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have successfully been using several scripts on startup by creating shortcuts to them in this directory:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

however one of the scripts will not load when I log back in after logging off. The script is a AHK script used as a toggle to switch between displays and sound sources:

```
#a::
toggle += 1 
if (toggle = 0)
{
    Run nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "BEDROOM"
    soundToggleBox("BEDROOM")
}
else if (toggle = 1)
{
    Run nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "LIVING_ROOM"
    soundToggleBox("LIVING_ROOM")
    toggle :=  -1 
Return

; Display sound toggle GUI
soundToggleBox(Device)
{
    IfWinExist, soundToggleWin
    {
        Gui, destroy
    }

Gui, +ToolWindow -Caption +0x400000 +alwaysontop
Gui, Add, text, x35 y8, Default sound: %Device%
SysGet, screenx, 0
SysGet, screeny, 1
xpos:=screenx-275
ypos:=screeny-100
Gui, Show, NoActivate x%xpos% y%ypos% h30 w200, soundToggleWin

SetTimer,soundToggleClose, 2000
}
soundToggleClose:
    SetTimer,soundToggleClose, off
    Gui, destroy
Return
```

The script runs fine when I execute.

So I looked up why this might not be loading and noticed that another user was using a different startup directory than the one shown above:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

I noticed that placing the shortcut to this AHK file in this directory ensured that it would load after logging back in to Windows, so my question is:

what are the differences between these two directories for startup items:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Comment: You mention a BAT file, but this looks like a PowerShell script. How exactly are you launching this? That may impact the launch method. System wide scripts in C:\Programdata.... can react differently than personal scripts in c:\users\userid\...

Comment: @Tonny no that's an Autohotkey script.

Comment: @WasifHasan Ok, its AutoHotkey, which looks a bit similar to PowerShell and I didn't look too closely, but that still doesn't answer my question about how you are exactly starting this.

Comment: yes, sorry it is AHK script not BAT. Edited question to reflect this, How am I launching this you asked? I am putting a shortcut to the script in startup folder,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppData contains application data which is per-User profile specific, and ProgramData contains application data for the whole local machine. So only reason I can think of is that you log back as a different user (when the program copies itself to AppData Startup) then the entry is not per-machine, then it does not execute.

The best way of adding startup programs is to add an entry to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (Local machine), or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (per-User) or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (Windows 32 on Windows 64 entries) registry keys.

Comment: thanks for this. It should be known that I am not logging in as different user, as I am the only user of the machine.

Comment: Just coming back to say that this currently doesn't work. I added all new entries for 'C:\ProgramData\Logishrd\LogiOptions\Software\Current\LogiOptionsMgr.exe' in REG but the only thing that seemed to work was to create a .bat file and put links to that in the startup directories.

Comment: Is it possible to track done why my user startup program failed to start?

Comment: Any logs down there?

Comment: Well it turned out that only PARTICULAR APPLICATION doesn't want to be started. Digging up later. The game has started succesfully. Maybe other application is console one that's why. Drilling down further.